# What actually is a “Modern Day Slavery Policy”?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, legal-terms, definition, slavery

On many businesses’ websites there is an unobtrusive link to a so-called modern day slavery policy. What is this, and what provisions does it fulfill or get governed by?

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak for others, but my employer's policy is to ensure compliance with, and raise heightened awareness of, the [Modern Slavery Act 2015](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/30/contents).

If I recall correctly, the Act's original working-title included "Day" but was dropped along the way.

Comment: Are companies required to post a compliance notice? If so, then what is the compliance notice intended to accomplish/ensure?

Comment: @Seekinganswers: See art 54 of the linked law. It's quite readable.

Comment: @Seekinganswers nope, but it's good PR in some circles. Just as stating you're "diverse" and "don't allow discrimination in the workplace". Both are implied by your residence in a place where such things are legal requirements, companies explicitly mention both anyway.

Comment: @jwenting https://www.xkcd.com/641

Comment: @Seekinganswers yup, and that happens for real. A brand of chewing gum here started advertising with "guaranteed free of plastic" last year... They mean the packaging, but the way it's worded hints at it being the actual chewing gum that's free of plastic.